# Command line xcode project running throwing error FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 4

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm writing a shell script which help me run automatically my xcode ios project and launch its build on simulator. As per now i can able to build my xcode project, launch simulator and auto install app on simulator. But failed to launch app on simulator, app crash after launching simulator and throwing an error,

```
    Build Begin
    Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/username
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES

    === BUILD TARGET BuddyAdmin OF PROJECT BuddyAdmin WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

    Check dependencies

    ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

    Instruments Usage Error : No template (-t) specified
    instruments, version 6.3 (57536)
    usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
    An error was encountered processing the command (code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 4.)
    Build End
    logout
```

And my script is,

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Build Begin
    xcodebuild -project /Users/username/Work/My_Projects/BuddyProjects/BuddyAdmin/BuddyAdmin.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -target BuddyAdmin ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/username
    xcrun instruments -w "iPad 2 (8.3 Simulator)"
    xcrun simctl install booted /Users/username/Buddy\ Admin\ 3.app
    xcrun simctl launch booted prefix.com.coname.proname
    echo Build End
```

I'm not able to find out what exact error it is. Not anywhere documented. I search a lot i found unique answer which is reset simulator, clean project and clean derived data but it won't work for me. I'm looking for actual cause of error and solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this today, and finally worked out this by enclosing my bundle id into "", i.e. "prefix.com.coname.proname", and also the string is **case sensitive**.    : )

Comment: I got my problem is lies on xcodebuild command .. now i can run all automatically.